# forward Walk animation

Tags: animation

https://youtu.be/jN9ne1J0BwI

Please click the link above and take a look at this two-step animation. I don't want to do a walk cycle where the character walks in place. However, I'd like to extend the animation beyond two steps. Is there a tutorial, on Youtube or elsewhere that'll teach me how to extend this walk? I don't want to animate each step.

Comment: You can duplicate keyframes, just select the one that make up the current cycle and copy them over, than you can duplicate 2 cycles at a time, tan 4 etc.

Comment: Search tutorials for _Actions_ and the _Nonlinear Animation_ panel: you can create your cycle as an action, then make it repeat as many times you want. The advantage over copy pasting the keyframes is that you can change you cycle as you like, the walk pastern will always update

Comment: thanks, but copying and pasting the keyframes does not take care of the problem because I also copy the location.

Comment: please share your file (only the armature) so that we can test on it

Comment: Here is the link from which you can download the file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=12RmDoMFnwfMfjbR9xBMu1SxzlUhflWsY